# How to hide common desktop icons on my profile?

Tags: windows-7

I share a PC with some other people in the office (we all work different hours).  They've installed a bunch of programs they use (AIM, etc...) that place a shortcut in `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.

If I delete the icon, it's also going to be gone from their desktops as well.  Is there a way to hide these icons on my desktop, yet have them be visible on other people's desktops?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no known way around it, but I know a little workaround: Select properties on the public folder, go to the security tab and revoke all permissions for your user profile, by dissalowing reading from it your account won't be able to see what shortcuts are inside \Public\Desktop\ - resulting in the behaviour you want - no icons/shortcuts will be loaded from it.

Answer (score 2):

If they persist across all accounts its because they are present on the "public", "default" or "all users" profile, therefore global. 
If you want them out of your profile, copy them to an account-specific location and out of global locations.

you can do these changes at `C:\Users` , where "C" stands for your windows root.

Comment: he wants to disable public shortcuts for ONLY his profile while maintaining them on other profiles, your answer does not really provide a solution for that? Or don't I understand something? :/

Comment: if they dont have a LOT of account, this would do it, if you read better. but still, your answer is more "clean".

Comment: in detail what i meant is: keep the shortcuts in their profile folders specifically and not in global folders that are shared by all accounts. maybe i placed my answer in a confusing way.

Comment: yeah depends on the office size, in my school there are ~1200 user accounts so by dissalowing reading from a public folder would be a "cleaner" solution indeed.

Comment: oh and bytheway, I can also say that ALOT of installers place shortcuts into the public folder without explicit user permission.

Comment: true that. also true the public folder is sort of sensitive on safety. yours is truly cleaner. +1

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn I am aware of the approach you provided, in fact, that's what I've been using.  The problem with it is that every time AIM or Skype or a myriad of other apps get an update or a patch, they reinstall the shortcut into the the "all users" account and I see it again.

Comment: indeed true. its for your best to use the other answer, which you marked as the best answer.